# Input fields scroll out of view

Tags: ios, uitextfield, ios8.1

On my iOS app, first screen shows some input fields. When the user is starting the app, that first screen shows up. As the user focuses on input, the fields scroll down automatically. This only happens in iOS 8.1 or above. I tested this in iOS 7.1 and it looks totally fine.

Comment: post your code for textfielddidbeginediting?  Are you using these in a table view or scroll view?

Comment: Not using textfielddidbeginediting , I am suspecting scrollview issue

Comment: Your not really giving a lot of information, maybe post some code or an example of the problem.  Could be an auto layout issue or perhaps you are calling a line of code in the wrong spot or that performs differently on iOS 7.1 and 8.1+